# Pipe output from program which only outputs to a file

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

`pico2wave` only supports outputting to a file (edit: with extension `.wav`). How can I coerce the output into a pipe for `aplay`, without cleaning up any named pipes or temporary files or a wrapper script?

Ie, `pico2wave -w tmp.wav "test" && aplay tmp.wav && rm tmp.wav` creates a temporary file, and is thus not what I'm looking for as a solution.

Comment: Another option might be a `LD_PRELOAD` hack that changes the system calls `pico2wave` uses to instead target the `stdout` device.

Comment: I am 95% sure that we’ve had this question before (either here or on [SU]), but I’ve spent ten minutes searching, and I can’t find it. The general solution (assuming that you’re using bash, and you don’t need to specify a particular extension) is *`prog1 inputs `* `>(cat)  | ` *`prog2`*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A note on the general solution: to many programs which require a filename you can give the path `/dev/stdout` (a link to `/proc/self/fd/1`, assuming said files exist) and they will happily send their output to `stdout`. One may also use process substitution in `bash` with `cat`, ie `foo -f >(cat) args | bar` (thanks, [g-man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325019/pipe-output-from-program-which-only-outputs-to-a-file/325020#comment571830_325019)).

Because `pico2wave` checks the file extension, a possible solution is to symlink `/dev/stdout` to a path with the appropriate extension, ideally somewhere such as `/var/local/`. This does create an extra file, but not per process:
`ln -s /dev/stdout /var/local/pico2wave.wav`, then `pico2wave -w /var/local/pico2wave.wav "test" | aplay` works.

Comment: If you use `/tmp/pico2wave.wav` then the file will be deleted whenever the system boots, so you at least wouldn't need to manually clean up the file.

Comment: I suppose what I want is "no setup/teardown steps"; I prefer `/var/local/` over `/tmp/` in that there is a one-time setup instead of per-boot, and that feels like the right place to put such a path on an individual machine.